# Can I break batteries by putting them in the wrong way?

Tags: batteries, damage

If I put in batteries the wrong way (+ and - sides reversed), is there a risk that I will break them? Or the device? Or start a fire?

In particular, I am talking about rechargeable Ni-MH eneloops and cheap electronic toys for kids, and most of the time not all of the batteries are put in the wrong way, just some of them are reversed (which is probably even worse, right).

Comment: Check out how Microsoft has *solved* the backwards battery dilemma, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/licensing/instaloadoverview.mspx).

Comment: But it requires licensing, so no one else will ever use it.

Comment: As a comment, Ni* batteries can put out hefty currents. I've had a small two AA battery holder melt when the wires got shorted for a few seconds.

Comment: Microsoft's may be the only battery holder which compensates for reverse polarity, but many devices use the shape of the battery ends to ensure that the positive terminal will only make contact with the positive end of a stack, and vice versa.  Devices with five or more batteries in a stack could be reverse-biased if one connected the end batteries in one polarity and the inner batteries the other way, but that's probably not a terribly common a scenario, and the properly-polarized batteries would help to impede the errant current.

Comment: @tyblu Link cannot be openend because Microsoft server tells there is a request block. Enter the name of the technique so people are able to search it on google.

Answer (score 10):

**Consumer Devices**

Almost all consumer electronics have protection in place to prevent any damage when connecting the battery backwards. Companies know they can't trust consumer to put the batteries in the correct orientation and it is usually cheaper for them to add the protection then it is to deal with support calls and returns.

**Batteries in your own device**

If you are wanting to make your own device, you will need to add protection or it will be almost guaranteed that you will have ICs that smoke. The battery itself probably wont be hurt. They can output ALOT of current. All of your ICs and polarized caps will usually break in such away that they will act like an open circuit. Because of this the batter will only have a short time where it is having to put out a lot of current.

**How to protect your device**

The easiest way to protect your electronics is to put a fuse in-line with your battery. This is a good all-purpose fail safe. Fuses are too slow to blow to protect all ICs, but at least it prevents your project from catching on fire.

If you place a single diode in series with your battery you can prevent any current flowing in the wrong direction. Do be prepared to see a 0.7v drop across the diode.

You can also use a 4 diode configuration to allow your circuit to continue to work regardless of how to battery gets connected. This disadvantage of this method is that you have 2 diode drops (about 1.4v).

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say that `Almost all consumer electronics have protection in place`. Consumer electronics is often about producing at extremely low cost. A common remote control for your stereo (produced by tens of millions) has 3 or 4 electronic components and can be produced for less than 1 dollar. I don't think there's room there for protection.

Comment: I can say that I have put batteries in my remotes backwards and haven't had a single issue (other then it not working until I swap them). In a remote, the current draw is very little, because of this the diode used can easily be less then half a cent at those large quantities.

Comment: @stevenvh here's another way to think of it. Let's say the extra diode costs $0.10. Now let’s say that 10% of people will accidentally put their batteries in the wrong direction. These people will then call saying their remote doesn't work. The company will then have to pay for all of the overhead and employee time dealing with the call. I could easily see this adding up to $1. The company would then probably have to assume that it wasn't the consumers fault and will send you out a new remote.

Comment: This will then cost them an extra $1 for the remote plus some more overhead associated with packing and sending out the new remote. So if you look at the net numbers now for 10 people, $0.10*10=$1 extra in parts for 10 remotes, out of these 10 remotes you can guess that 1 will be hooked up wrong, earlier I showed how this could cost the company $2 (and that’s assuming the company is making the customer pay for the shipping).

Comment: So the company put $1 up to save $2. Sounds like a good deal to me. Now, I mentioned earlier that diodes can actually be purchased for half a cent. If I use that number it’s more like it cost the company 5 cents to save $2. It’s a no brainer to me. Even if only 1% of people put their batteries in wrong it still makes sense.

Comment: Don't forget that for most remotes, the battery likely only connects to the controller IC (which runs every other part). Therefore, they can just fab the diode into the IC die to reduce the costs even further.

Comment: @stevenvh in many countries there are regilations in place which require consumer electronics to have reverse voltage protection when used with batteries so the cost of not putting the diode there is not selling at all ;)

Comment: In many consumer devices, the reverse battery protection is mechanical, and costs nothing to the manufacturer.  Mould a couple of pieces of plastic, one each side of the battery positive terminal.  If you insert a cell the wrong way round, the flat negative terminal doesn't make contact because the plastic gets in the way.

Answer (score 3):

If you put one of two batteries the wrong way, then there's no problem, neither for the batteries nor for the device; total voltage is +Vbat - Vbat = 0V. No voltage is no current, so your batteries won't discharge. It's just that the device won't do a thing.
If you reverse both batteries the result may be worse: most likely the device will be damaged, esp. if it's electronic. The batteries may survive without too much damage unless the reversal causes a short circuit.

Comment: "esp. if it's electronic" what else can you can you power batteries with that aren't electronic?

Comment: @Dean: small motors?

Comment: @Stevenvh "Electronics is the branch of science and technology which makes use of the controlled motion of electrons through different media."-wikipedia If you have an electric motor, you are controlling the motion of electrons in the motor.

Comment: @Kellenjb: lighting an incandescent lamp also involves the movement of more than a few electrons, but I don't think anyone will call the electrical circuit in your house electronics.

Comment: @Stevenvh its all relative to who looks at it. Power distribution engineers and Electricians would definitely consider them electronics. Just because you consider it something so simple or something that is just a given doesn't mean its still not electronics.

Comment: @Dean -- You can put the batteries in a flashlight with an incandescent bulb the wrong way without any damage.  I wouldn't call that electronic.

Comment: @dean, @kellenjb, you all understood what Stevenvh meant. Just be argumentative for fun. @Stevenvh, I think they tricked you into a pyrrhic victory. You may be right, but the argument was not worth it.

Comment: +1 For learning a new term: [Pyrrhic victory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_victory). Flippin' histogeographic catchphrases...

Comment: "If you put one of two batteries the wrong way, then there's no problem". How about two out of three?

Comment: @Thilo - two right, one wrong = no problem. You'll still have a positive voltage, but 1.5V instead of 4.5V. One right, two wrong = possible problems. The total voltage will be -1.5V, and that may be enough to damage the device.

Comment: I just learnt there is a problem if one battery is position incorrectly, since 2 batteries never have exactly the same voltage. So +Vbat - Vbat = 0 V is only true in a perfect world.

Comment: @tcrosley Huh. That never occurred to me when I was trying to figure out which way around the batteries were supposed to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you put in both batteries the wrong way and apply a negative voltage, your device may be damaged. The designers may not added a protection circuit (i.e. a diode) because it's battery powered and they need all the voltage they can get.

If a device causes a short, that can damage the batteries. Otherwise it's more likely that the batteries will damage(destroy) any IC that gets a voltage outside their maximum ratings.

Answer (score 2):

The answers I read here assume a single battery or several batteries in series ( + connected to - ).
There are however devices in which batteries are connected in parallel ( + to + and - to - ).
This is to increase power rather than voltage.
A typical case is a so-called "power bank" in which up to 6 18650 batteries may be in parallel.
I have some Chinese samples and none of them has a protection of any kind.

And powerful they are !!!
Should you put one battery in the wrong (reversed) way, you make a bomb !!!
Extremely high current will flow in circle through 2 batteries.
They will rapidly heat up and explode, causing fire and personal injuries hazard.
There are some exploding 18650 Youtube videos around to watch.

The best self-defense I see is

- to cut the plate making the + contacts in separate pieces if not already
- to connect them to the + source through a resettable fuse each

Of all the measurements I made, current never exceeded 1.5A per battery.
But the power pack rating may be up to 2A, 2.5A max.
So, the fuses choice could be 10×2A SMD @ 1.85€ or 10×3.5A SMD @ 2.75€
Wired fuses are more expensive.
That's what I'm seeing right now on eBay.

Or just a thin wire. At what current does a multistalk wire stalk melt?